# Get ID from GCM message

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Can I get the ID of a GCM message?

When I send a message to GCM Server, it returns an ID. 
I have a table in my database where I store IDs of sent messages.
When I get the push notification at the client, is there a way to get this ID?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that identifier is not sent to the client. If you need an identifier for the purpose of sending a delivery acknowledgment from your app to your server, you'll have to create your own unique identifier at the server and pass it in the payload of the GCM message to the app.